# Iterate over the same list twice in Jinja2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm trying to print a list of tags in two separate places, but the second time I for/in the list, it doesn't loop.

```
<ul>
# for tag in tags
    <li><a href="/my-tags/{{tag.name}}">{{tag.name}}</a></li>
# endfor
</ul>

<ul>
# for tag in tags
    <li><a href="/my-tags/{{tag.name}}">{{tag.name}}</a></li>
# endfor
</ul>
```

The second UL ends up empty if I put that in my template.

Any ideas?

Edit:

This is how I'm populating the tags variable.

```
contact_data.append({'name': 'Placeholder', 'emails': contact.emails, 'tags': [tag for tag in nt_tags.get_tags_by_taggee(contact)]})
```

Edit againt:

Logged what I'm passing and its

```
[<nt_tags.Tag object at 0x0000000005CAFF28>, <nt_tags.Tag object at 0x0000000005CAFFD0>]
```

Which looks like just a list not an iterator right?

Comment: having this exact problem now.

Comment: I logged the second loop and at that point the list is empty. No idea why. I have ended up having to pass two duplicate lists to the template for now. Will update if I come across a better solution.

Answer (score 6):

If `tags` is an iterator, then at the end of the first iteration, there won't be anything left to iterate. You could materialise it to a list before passing it to your template `eg: list(tags)` in your context...

Comment: I updated question with how I'm creating the tags variable. What I think I'm doing is creating a new list that shouldn't be an iterator when I assign it to 'tags', is that what I'm actually doing?