# Django: jinja2 code not working when iterated over the same list twice

Tags: python, django

I have an html file in my django project as follows:

```
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="list-group">
                {% for image in images %}
                <li class="list-group-item">{{ image.name}}
                <img class="img-responsive" src='http://krishna.com{{ image.path }}' />
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
            <ul class="list-group">
                {% for image in images %}
                <li class="list-group-item">{{ image.name}}
                <img class="img-responsive" src='http://krishna.com{{ image.path }}' />
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

the content is showing for the `<div class="col-sm-3">`

but no content is being shown for `<div class="col-sm-9">`

In the image below, even thought the jinja code is same for both the divs, it shows only on one side.

One may ask why i am doing. I am just testing.

[image]

Edit:

I am generating the list in the following way:

```
def gallery(request):
    import os, sys
    img_list = os.scandir('/home/shared/pictures')
    return render(request,'blog/gallery.html', {'images': img_list})
```

Comment: is this your exact code?

Comment: What is *images*? what have you tried so far?

Comment: images is an array of file names. check the edited question with the image

Comment: I found only one similar question. but couldnt find an answer in it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651965/iterate-over-the-same-list-twice-in-jinja2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be passing a [generator object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/1268926) instead of a list / tuple.

The difference is that you can iterate over the generator object only once.

For example (below is the last / equivalent line in your view that renders the template)

```
return render(request, "template.html", {'images': (i for i in range(10))})
```

Will result in `images` being iterated over only once. (In your example, the `col-sm-9` block will be empty).

If you need to iterate over something more than once, you must pass it as a list or tuple.

```
return render(request, "template.html", {'images': list(i for i in range(10))})
```

Comment: so in my case. (see the edited question) i am getting a list of files from a directory. So how to make it a list

Comment: Try `{'images': list(img_list)}`

Comment: If you see img_list has a path and name for each item. If i try that, it will only show me the path

Comment: That is not true, calling list doesn't change the structure of the items in your iterable.