# Jinja nested loop - inside loop only works the first time

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm relatively new to Python, Flask, and Jinja, so I hope this question makes sense. I'm using a for loop to iterate through 2 arrays to create a form on a webpage. Basically, it is a list of dropdown menus. For each 'port' in the 'ports' array, a dropdown list is created with options specified by the elements in the 'zones' array.

```
<div class="grid-wrapper center">
{% for port in ports %}
    <div class="grid-item">Port {{ port['portNum'] }}
        <input id="portID{{ port['portID'] }}" type="hidden" name="portID" value="{{ port['portID']}}">
        <input id="description{{ port['portID'] }}" class="grid-item-textbox" name="description" value="{{ port['description'] }}">
        <select id="zoneID{{ port['portID'] }}" class="grid-item-select" name="zoneID" value="{{port['zoneID']}}">
        {% for zone in zones %}
            <option value="{{ zone['zoneID'] }}">{{ zone['name'] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Generated HTML:
[image: Generated HTML]

Rendered webpage:
[image: Rendered webpage]

The outer loop works fine. The webpage shows a dropdown for each element of the 'port' array, but the options from the 'zones' array only appear in the first dropdown. It's as though the inner loop is complete skipped after the first iteration of the outer loop. The generated HTML has nothing inside the select element.

Comment: What is `zones` exactly? Please post the `render_template(...)` code. Feels like an exhausted iterator.

Comment: The render_template call looks like this: `render_template('portsTable.html', section = 'content', switch = switch, ports = ports, zones = zones)` An exhausted iterator sounds likely, but I think I assumed it would "reset" each time the inner loop was restarted. Is fixing this as simple as having the `zones` be an array within `ports` so that each port has its own `zones` list?

Comment: Please post where `zones` comes from or how it is created. Iterators do not reset. But an interatable like a list can be iterated multiple times. So `render_template(..., zones = list(zones))` might fix it since it stores all values and can be reused.

Comment: `zones`, `switch`, and `ports` are all returned from SQLite queries. The one for `zones` is `zones = db.execute("SELECT zoneID, name FROM lyntecZone ORDER BY name")`.

Comment: `zones` is likely being returned as an generator rather than a list. Check out [jinja2 code not working when iterated over the same list twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39456156/django-jinja2-code-not-working-when-iterated-over-the-same-list-twice)

Comment: Ah. That's it. After building a list separately and passing that to `render_template` it works exactly as expected. Thanks.

Comment: curley braces and % signs everywhere.  i will stay away from jinja. what a horrible construct given all the beautiful code that exists.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug with the library you're using, you should report it to the library's maintainers.

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
<div class="grid-wrapper center">
{% for port in ports %}
    <div class="grid-item">Port {{ port['portNum'] }}
        <input id="portID{{ port['portID'] }}" type="hidden" name="portID" value="{{ port['portID']}}">
        <input id="description{{ port['portID'] }}" class="grid-item-textbox" name="description" value="{{ port['description'] }}">
        <select id="zoneID{{ port['portID'] }}" class="grid-item-select" name="zoneID" value="{{port['zoneID']}}">
        {% assign zones_ = zones %}
        {% for zone in zones_ %}
            <option value="{{ zone['zoneID'] }}">{{ zone['name'] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```